# Change font size without messing with Tkinter button size

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter, font-size

I am having trouble **changing the font size of a button** in Tkinter, when I attempt to do it *the button also expands/contracts* based on the size of the text. Is there a way I can alter the text size with the button's size anchored in place?

I ran across this while designing a tic-tac-toe application, however to save you the trouble, here is a very **minimal example** of the problem in practice:

```
import Tkinter as tk

MyWindow = tk.Tk()
MyWindow.geometry("500x550")


button = tk.Button(MyWindow,text="Hello!",width=17,height=10,font=('Helvetica', '20'))
button.grid(row=1, column=1)

MyWindow.mainloop()
```

The **most important part** here is `font=('Helvetica', '15')` or more specifically, the *number 15*. If you **change that number** and run this again, not only will the text be bigger/smaller, *but so will the button*! How do I get around this?

It's probably a *really* simple problem. I've just gotten started with Tkinter. Thanks in advance for any help I receive!

Comment: Why are you passing the font size as a string instead of a number?

Comment: @martineau Well it actually doesn't matter which way I pass it, but I guess I found documentation online that passed it that way.

Comment: Still, it doesn't help me in solving the real problem at hand

Comment: @martineau Try running the code with the number 15, then replace it with the number 20, look at the difference between the button sizes.

Comment: Also do import Tkinter as tk. And what os are you using?

Comment: Ah, thanks :) @abccd Also, linux,

Comment: The problem is the `height=10` in the `Button` constructor call. That's how many text **lines** tall the button should be (not pixels), which depends on character height of the font being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width of the button is defined in units of character width. In your case the button is defined to be 17 characters wide. So changing the character width by (ie changing the font size) changes the width of the button. AFAIK, the only way around that is to put the button into a Frame, because a Frame can define it's size in pixels. Here's a new kind of Button that does exactly that:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Warspyking(tk.Frame):
    '''A button that has it's width and height set in pixels'''
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.rowconfigure(0, minsize=kwargs.pop('height', None))
        self.columnconfigure(0, minsize=kwargs.pop('width', None))
        self.btn = tk.Button(self, **kwargs)
        self.btn.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.config = self.btn.config

#example usage:
MyWindow = tk.Tk()
MyWindow.geometry("500x550")

from itertools import cycle
fonts = cycle((('Helvetica', '11'),('Helvetica', '15'),('Helvetica', '20')))
def chg():
    button.config(font=next(fonts))

button = Warspyking(MyWindow,text="Click me!",width=200,height=100 ,font=next(fonts), command=chg)
button.grid(row=1, column=1)

MyWindow.mainloop()
```

EDIT: Based on what I learned from Bryan Oakley, here's a much neater implementation:

```
class Warspyking(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        self.img = tk.PhotoImage()
        tk.Button.__init__(self, master, image=self.img, compound='center', **kwargs)
```

I should also add that I very much agree with Bryan: Using this is probably a sign that you are doing something wrong. You should let tkinter handle sizing.

Comment: Your class declaration and stuff is scaring me. I'm only starting out in both python and tkinter haha.

Comment: GUIs rely heavily on classes, as do many other things in python. Jump in.

Answer (score 7):

Typically, when you give a button a width, that width is measured in characters (ie: `width=1` means the width of one average sized character). However, if the button has an image then the width specifies a size in pixels.

A button can contain both an image and text, so one strategy is to put a 1x1 pixel as an image so that you can specify the button size in pixels. When you do that and you change the font size, the button will not grow since it was given an absolute size.

Here is an example that illustrates the technique. Run the code, then click on "bigger" or "smaller" to see that the text changes size but the button does not.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont

def bigger():
    size = font.cget("size")
    font.configure(size=size+2)

def smaller():
    size = font.cget("size")
    size = max(2, size-2)
    font.configure(size=size)

root = tk.Tk()
font = tkFont.Font(family="Helvetica", size=12)

toolbar = tk.Frame(root)
container = tk.Frame(root)

toolbar.pack(side="top", fill="x")
container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

bigger = tk.Button(toolbar, text="Bigger", command=bigger)
smaller = tk.Button(toolbar, text="Smaller", command=smaller)

bigger.pack(side="left")
smaller.pack(side="left")

pixel = tk.PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)
for row in range(3):
    container.grid_rowconfigure(row, weight=1)
    for column in range(3):
        container.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=1)
        button = tk.Button(container, font=font, text="x",
            image=pixel, compound="center", width=20, height=20)
        button.grid(row=row, column=column)

root.mainloop()
```

All of that being said, there is almost never a time when this is a good idea. If the user wants a larger font, the whole UI should adapt. Tkinter is really good at making that happen, to the point where it all mostly works by default.

Comment: This is so brilliant and easy to be understood! As a mark, this answer is on `python 2.x`, in order to test on `python 3.x`, please edit `Tkinter` as `tkinter` in the first line, and `import tkFont` to `from tkinter import font` in the second line, and `tkFont.Font(` to `font.Font(` in the following, then you are all set!

Comment: Setting the `minsize` option in `.grid_columnconfigure` and `.grid_rowconfigure` will work too.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution of this problem. I was trying to solve a similar problem: I want to put image on label. I set the image size equal to label size. When I have been trying to put it with command `label.config(image=img)` the label size grow. The image have the size I set to it, so it didn't cover label completely. I was using grid manager. All size were not entered in advanced but calculated by Tkinter. I was using `grid_columnconfigure` and `grid_rowconfigure`. The solution I found is to put this label with image (or button in Your case) to `LabelFrame` and set `grid_propagate` to `False`.
Code example:

```
MyWindow = tk.Tk()
MyWindow.geometry("500x550")

#create LabelFrame (200x200)
label = tk.LabelFrame(MyWindow, width=200, height=200)

#grid manager to set label localization
labelk.grid(row=0, column=0)

#label row and column configure: first argument is col or row id
label.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
label.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

#cancel propagation
label.grid_propagate(False)

#Create button and set it localization. You can change it font without changing size of button, but if You set too big not whole will be visible
button = t.Button(label, text="Hello!", font=('Helvetica', '20'))

#Use sticky to button took up the whole label area
button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw')

MyWindow.mainloop()
```

Result for font size 40 and 20:

[image: Image for font size 40]
[image: Image for font size 20]

Example for creating button with dynamic size by grid manager:

```
MyWindow = tk.Tk()
MyWindow.geometry("500x550")

#Divide frame on 3x3 regions
for col in range(3):
    MyWindow.grid_columnconfigure(col, weight=1)
for row in range(3):
    MyWindow.grid_rowconfigure(row, weight=1)

label = tk.LabelFrame(MyWindow)

#Put label in the middle
label.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nesw')
label.grid_propagate(False)
label.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
label.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
button = tk.Button(label, text="Hello!", font=('Helvetica', '30'))
button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw')
MyWindow.mainloop()
```

It is late answer, but maybe it will help someone.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67241484/14715170 Can you please help me for this ?